# MySQL - Implementing a function encoding a string into a binary field

Tags: mysql, string, binary, data-conversion

in MySQL there is a function called `UNHEX` which takes a string like `'1DB8948899F511E6A18374D02B45FC30'` and turns it into a sequence of bits, a binary field. It is what I use for storing `UUID`s. The reverse operation is implemented in the function `HEX`.

I store protein sequences, each protein sequence is a finite sequence of letters, there are at most 21 different letters. Instead of storing each sequence as a clear text, I would like to store them as binary fields.

Thus I would like to implement a custom function, similar to `UNHEX`, which replaces each letter by a given sequence of 5 bits (this quantity of bits is enough). I will also implement the reciprocal.

How to implement such a function?

I looked into the function `COMPRESS`, but it provides longer output when run on sequences of length around 63, 64, and the compression factor for sequences of length below 150 is less than the `1.6` factor of compression that I would achieve with my custom function. The sequences with length below 150 are numerous, thus, I will not gain much by using the function `COMPRESS`.

My MySQL version is 14.14 Distrib 5.5.52, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64), and you can think a protein sequence as a finite sequence of letters from A to U (the actual letters are not relevant here, I will adapt the code).

What I would like to make is a function which take a string made of these letters from A to U as argument and turn them into a sequence of bits. since `2^4 < 21 <= 2^5`, 5 bits for each letter is needed and enough.

I am looking into making a plugin for MySQL which will define both these functions. Am I going too far? Is there an easier way? If so, will the functions gain efficiency by being programmed into a plugin?

Comment: Note that you have described `HEX()` and `UNHEX()` backwards.  `HEX()` *unpacks* 8 bits per byte of binary data into 4 bits per byte of hexadecimal, `UNHEX()` *packs* 4 bits per byte of hex-encoded data into 8 bits per byte of binary data.

Comment: For your use case, what are the symbols in the  21-symbol alphabet?  Is it the letters A through U, or something else? Also? What version of MySQL?

Comment: I would suggest having a look at how the base64_encode / decode functions are implemented as they use 6 bits. Also, how to convert  convert to number base 32?

Comment: Thanks Ryan. I have found this link: https://github.com/y-ken/mysql-udf-base64/blob/master/base64.c and I will look into that. I think it answers my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I need to adapt the function base64encode and base64decode.
The source for these functions is found here:

https://github.com/y-ken/mysql-udf-base64/blob/master/base64.c